# Finite satisfiable, then satisfiable

Tags: logic

Let's take a complete set $\Sigma \subseteq$ Fml$_\mathcal{P}$ (for every $p \in\mathcal{P}$ we have $p\in\Sigma$ or $\neg p \in\Sigma$). Now I would like to prove that if $\Sigma$ is finite satisfiable (every finite subset $\Sigma_0 \subseteq \Sigma$ is satisfiable), then $\Sigma$ is also satisfiable (There exists a $\delta: \mathcal{P}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $\delta^*(F) = 1$ for every $F\in\Sigma$).

My idea was to give a prove by contradiction, but I can't see how to become it.

Comment: The fact that $\Sigma$ is complete means that there is only one reasonable choice for $\delta$. Do you see what it is? Can you show that this $\delta$ witnesses that $\Sigma$ is satisfiable?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I thought that I could take $\delta(p_i)=1$ if $p_i \in \Sigma$ and $\delta(p_i)=0$ if $p_i \not\in\Sigma$. But I don't see what I can do with that.

Comment: Great. Now suppose this $\delta$ does *not* witness satisfiability of $\Sigma$. What would that mean?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ooh I see. If there existst an $F$ for which $\delta(F)=0$ we have a finite subset that exists of the $p_i$'s and other parts of $F$ that isn't satisfiable. Thanks!

Comment: If you can now answer the question yourself, I encourage you to write an answer to your own question and accept it, so that the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Okay, I will do! Thanks for the help!